# Numpy - load csv with first row as names immediately to a structured array?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to avoid having to predefine the names of column headers in numpy/pandas to create a structured array, and instead have numpy/pandas read in the first row as the header names, and load the rest of the data to a structured array? E.g. for this data,

```
#        Date     low    open   close
#  2015-08-08  266.00  280.04  266.82
#  2015-07-08  233.00  280.04  266.82
```

I would want to call some function like `a = pd.read_csv()` and be able to access the columns immediately as `a['Date']`, without predefining `names = [Date, low, open, close]` and having to pass that into `read_csv()`. Is this possible?

Comment: `genfromtxt` takes `names=True, dtype=None`. `loadtxt` should have something similar.  You may need to disable comments.

Comment: Is the `#` really part of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) then first row data create columns of `df`.

So work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
#if necessary change default parameter sep=','
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')
print (df)
         Date    low    open   close
0  2015-08-08  266.0  280.04  266.82
1  2015-07-08  233.0  280.04  266.82

print (df.columns)
Index(['Date', 'low', 'open', 'close'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, a numpy example:

```
rec_arr = np.genfromtxt("try.csv", delimiter = " ", names=True, dtype=None)
rec_arr
array([(b'2015-08-08',  266.,  280.04,  266.82),
       (b'2015-07-08',  233.,  280.04,  266.82)],
      dtype=[('Date', 'S10'), ('low', '<f8'), ('open', '<f8'), ('close', '<f8')])
```

Then, you can access columns like:

```
rec_arr['close']
array([ 266.82,  266.82])
```

and do some math as usual:

```
rec_arr['close'].mean()
266.81999999999999
```